# Area of intersection of connected components

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, connected-components

I am doing a segmentation task using MATLAB. To analyze the performance of my algorithm, I need the area of intersection of each connected component in both images.

In what way are the connected components labelled in an image? Also, does `PixelIdxList` list all the linear indices of points that are a part of the connected component?

Comment: What is `PixelIdxList`? one of the outputs from `bwconncomp`, I assume? Edit your question to show your actual code.

Comment: use `sparse`! it's not a trivial use, but it can give you the area of intersections.

Answer (score 0):

> In what way are the connected components labelled in an image?

`bwconncomp` discovers the connected components by either using 4-(or 8)-connected neighborhood for 2D images or 6-(18, 26)-connected neighborhood for 3D images. Labels are enumerated starting from the left-top corner in 2D and in 3D (first slice).

> Also, does PixelIdxList list all the linear indices of points that are a part of the connected component?

Yes. So, once both images are labelled, you can use `intersect` to find intersection between different labels. Also, you might want to read about [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

Comment: It is using a 4 connected neighborhood. I will try intersect if it works to find intersection between labels in both images.